# I cannot view my gltf file in Autodesk A360

Tags: autodesk-viewer, revit-api, autodesk

I exported my Revit file in gltf format. I was able to view this gltf file in various web and desktop viewers, but my file did not open in autodesk a360. A similar question on Stackowerflow didn't come to a conclusion either. What is the reason of this?

Answer (score 0):

The glTF loader in Forge Viewer is not (yet) 100% spec-compliant which means that there can be rare cases of glTF files it won't be able to load. In those situations I would suggest to:

- report the issue via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, if possible including a sample glTF file (would be kept confidential), so that the viewer team can improve the glTF loader accordingly
- using the standard `THREE.GLTFLoader` (just be careful about the version; Forge Viewer is built on top of three.js R71) to load the glTF into a standard `THREE.Mesh`, and insert the mesh into the viewer using the `SceneBuilder` extension